# SSH for Bash Script (SSH-Agent)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ssh, bitbucket

Not sure if this is a duplicate question but I really can't find any solution to my problem.

The problem is that I can't run the following command.

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT1="cd /path/to/project;"
SCRIPT2="git pull;"
ssh "production" ${SCRIPT1} "ssh-agent /bin/bash; ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_bitbucket_key;" ${SCRIPT2}
```

Still a newbie in bash and ssh so I am not sure also if this is the correct way of doing this.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Comment: Does the command work for somebody else but not for you, or has it never worked for anybody? If it just doesn't work for you, what error message are you getting? If it hasn't worked for anybody, I'd try putting both $SCRIPT1 and $SCRIPT2 inside the double-quotes of the ssh command.

Comment: change first line to `#!/bin/bash -vx` to see variable substitutions as they happen in each cmd. I think you'll see the problem. Don't be confused that all strings are now single quoted on the lines beginning with `+`. That's just the way the debugger "normalizes" its inputs. Good luck.

Comment: As an aside, putting the remote commands in variables is dubious practice. Perhaps instead create a function which runs its argument in a remote shell, like `prod "cd /path/to/project; git pull` where `prod` could be something like `prod () { ssh production ssh-agent bash -c "ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_bitbucket_key; $@"; }`

Comment: What does '$@' means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your script is that you are starting `ssh-agent` running a new instance of `bash`.  The Bash executing your commands has no access to this agent.  Instead, you want

```
ssh "production" "${SCRIPT1}
    eval \$(ssh-agent)
    ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_bitbucket_key
    ${SCRIPT2}"
```

(The dollar sign after `eval` has to be escaped because the unescaped dollar signs will be evaluated by the local shell before starting the `ssh` command.)